# Access to variable of a python class from Robot Framework

Tags: python, oop, robotframework

I have a python file for example Animals.py, inside I defined 3 different classes like that:

```
#Animals.py
class Animal:
    listAnimal=["dog","cat"] #<------------
    def __init__(self):
        #Animal constructor
        pass

class Dog(Animal):
    def __ini__(self):
        #dog constructor
        pass
class Cat(Animal):
    def __ini__(self):
        #cat constructor
        pass
```

I would like to get access to the class variable **listAnimal**

I am not an expert of RF I tried to use that:

```
Import Library   Animal
${ListAnimal}   Animal.listAnimal
```

could you give some suggestion on that please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the **[Get Library Instance](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Library%20Instance)** keyword from the BuiltIn library to get the currently active instance of the specified test library. Then you can use the **[Extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax)** to access the list and its elements.

Example:

```
${lib}=     Get Library Instance    Animal
Log     ${lib.listAnimal[0]}    # should log 'dog'
Log     ${lib.listAnimal[1]}    # should log 'cat'
${ListAnimal}=    Set Variable   ${lib.listAnimal}
```

Answer (score 4):

I added a new function to the file Animals.py

```
def getListAnimals():
    return Animal.listAnimal
```

And I am now only using this function in the robot framework:

```
Import Library   Animals.py
${ListAnimal}   Get List Animals
```