# How to access variable defined in python file in to robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

**variablefile.py**

```
varname=None
```

**Base.py**

```
Import variablefile as testVar

class Base:
  testVar.varName=3

  def print_val():
     print(testVar.varName)
```

**test.robot**

```
***Settings***
Variables variablefile.py

***Keywords***
Get variable value
   Log ${testVar}
```

When I'm debugging, I'm able to see the variable value as 3 in base.py but when i try to use the variable in robot file, I'm getting 'None' instead of '3'. Can someone help me in this

Comment: in `variablefile.py` you have variable `varname` without upper `N` but this can be a typo.

Comment: @furas, can you please suggest me the way, that i can access the variable in to my robot file

Comment: you can't change it this way. `import` loads variables to memory and you change values in memory. But this can't change values in file `variablefile.py` which you load in test.robot`. You would have to write values back to file.

Comment: How we can write value back to in a file

Comment: there is no special function to write it back in python file. You have to read it as normal text, edit it as normal text, and write it back as normal text. `open()`. `read()`, `write()`.

Comment: in documentation I see it can read `Variables` from file `.yaml` and for this format Python should have module to write data.

Comment: maybe you should get value from class `Base` - [Access to variable of a python class from Robot Framework - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072948/access-to-variable-of-a-python-class-from-robot-framework)